# Workaround for a Gmail composer arrow key/cursor bug

Tags: gmail

I trigger a minor cursor bug in Gmail's composer all the time, and it's  driving me nuts. Here's the bug:

1. Reply to an email and type something.
2. With the cursor at the end of the line, press the down arrow key to highlight the "..." quote chip.
3. Press the left arrow key. The cursor appears back at the end of the line of text.
4. Type a letter. Gmail inserts a newline and the letter appears on the next line.

I often use <kbd>down</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> as a shortcut to get to the end of the current line (since Gmail doesn't support Ctrl-E), so this happens to me all the time.

I've inspected the DOM when this happens. The composer uses a content-editable div inside an iframe, and its contents (before the quote chip) are the same both before and after I trigger the bug, so I'm guessing the change in state is somewhere in JavaScript. Google's JS is compiled, so that's where I stop dumpster diving and ask for help.